# Show the solution for $\mathcal{F}(e^{-\left | t \right |})$

Tags: integration, fourier-series, transformation

I'm trying to show that 
$$\mathcal{F}(e^{-\left | t \right |}) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1 + w^2)}$$
Knowing that the Fourier transform is in the form
$$\mathcal{F}(f(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)e^{-iwt}dt$$
Someone can help me?

Comment: Did you even *try* to do the integrals?

Comment: I didn't know how to deal with $abs(t)$ =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral splits into
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t}e^{-iwt} \, dt + \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{t} e^{-iwt} \, dt. $$
Changing variables in the second integral, you can rewrite this as
$$ 2\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \cos{wt} \, dt. $$
Now integrate by parts twice, and you find
$$ \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \cos{wt} \, dt = 1-w^2 \int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} \, \cos{wt} \, dt, $$
which you can rearrange and then multiply by the other factors to get the result.

Comment: On the off-chance OP is familiar with the Laplace transform, the second integral expression could be handled easily by consider $\mathcal{L}\{\cos\omega t\}=\int\limits_0^\infty e^{-st}\cos\omega t\,dt$ when $s=1$.

Comment: Yes, but by the same argument you can just look up this Fourier transform in a book of tables in the first place. Real Mathematicians™ do their own integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear with the post below, the reason to split the integral as such is because:
$$|t|= \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       -t & : t \le 0\\
       t & : t > 0
     \end{array}
   \right.\\ $$

$$f(t)=e^{-|t|}= \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
      e^{-(-t)} & : t \le 0\\
       e^{-(t)} & : t > 0
     \end{array}
   \right.\\ $$

$$f(t)= \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
      e^{t} & : t \le 0\\
       e^{-t} & : t > 0
     \end{array}
   \right.\\ $$